# spring-boot + cloud log4j version compatibity issue when using SerialisedLayout socket appender

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am developing an app in spring boot + gradle and using version 1.5.x version (tried 1.5.10, 1.5.2 and 1.5.1). The log4j version used by boot is 2.7

Everything works fine normally but I need to use a Socket Appender to send the logs to another host. This host uses log4j version 2.4

When I try to start my app I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;
```

I have excluded the spring-starter-logging in gradle

```
configurations {
// Replace "spring-boot-starter-logging" with log4j
compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
compile.exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
compile.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
```

The exception I get on the server side with default log4j verison is:

```
2018-02-07 16:03:59,344 [ Thread-4] ERROR org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.TcpSocketServer.9001 [] [env=;ses=;pag=;req=] - IOException encountered while reading from socket
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent$LogEventProxy; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8634075037355293699, local class serialVersionUID = -7139032940312647146
```

If anyone has any clue it would be very helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could gist/github an example project as a demonstration

Comment: I found the SocketAppender in log4j 2.3/2.4 is using the SerializedLayout which does not take any parameter. The objects gets serialized using ObjectOutputStream and deserialized at the server side. The serial version ID was updated which caused the issue. As I had no control in the server side, I had little choice but to include the 2.3 log4j jars. Also, the spring has a log4j class which has log file as lo4j.xml hardcoded. After including the default file (no profile specific files any more) and version change I can see that the logs are getting sent