# Abstract method error when pushing jhipster micro service to cloud foundry

Tags: maven, spring-boot, log4j, jhipster, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push my jhipster microservice to Cloud foundry. The micro service works correctly locally when I package it up for production, but it fails on the push to Cloud Foundry.

Background: I have a jar from the EGADS library, but I changed some of the source code for the functionality that I wanted. So I am using that as a 3rd party jar file in my micro service.

The logs from cloud foundry are as follows:

> 2018-08-15T15:42:14.769-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.769-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.769-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:472)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:442)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.770-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:254)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:425)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:442)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jLog.(LogFactory.java:199)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jDelegate.createLog(LogFactory.java:166)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:109)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:99)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:198)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] at com.comcast.egads.EgadsApp.main(EgadsApp.java:60)
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.771-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] ... 8 more
>       2018-08-15T15:42:14.798-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Exit status 1

Here is my pom file dependencies for the Micro service (wasn't enough room for the whole pom file):

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- parent POM declares this dependency in default (compile) scope -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.lbordowitz.openforecast</groupId>
          <artifactId>openforecast</artifactId>
          <version>0.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.comcast.egads</groupId>
          <artifactId>comcastEgads</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Could the problem also stem from the pom file from the 3rd party jar I am using? I am just trying to figure out where the problems comes from.

I have looked at [How to set up Spring Boot and log4j2 properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389512/how-to-set-up-spring-boot-and-log4j2-properly), [Log4J 2 version not working with RabbitMQ & Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447245/log4j-2-version-not-working-with-rabbitmq-spring-boot), [spring-boot + cloud log4j version compatibity issue when using SerialisedLayout socket appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665031/spring-boot-cloud-log4j-version-compatibity-issue-when-using-serialisedlayout), and more but I haven yet to find anything that solves my issue.

Comment: You can tell if it has to do with your 3rd party JAR by trying to deploy without it.

Comment: but that would mess up all the imports and functionality inside the microservice wouldn't it?@JonRuddell

Comment: Ya you would need to comment out that code, but it will tell you right away if that's causing the issue or not.  Have you tried running in prod locally?

Comment: Yeah locally, prod works fine I'm able to call all my endpoints fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, my entire microservice doesn't work if I comment out everything from the 3rd party library.